# Cakephp saveAssociated and SaveAll Nothing Working Properlly

Tags: model, save, cakephp-2.0, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am developing my application with cakephp 2.4.6. i know there are lots of posts in the stackoverflow related to saveAssociated issue.I have implemented several HABTM relationship in my database and now i am struggling a lot because of its unexpected behaviour.
I have

```
                Model  Details

               TEmployeeProfile HABTM TAddress
               TEmPloyeeProfile  HABTM TUserGroup
```

my table names are

```
          employee_profiles , t_addresses,t_addresses_employee_profiles,
           t_user_groups,employee_profiles_t_user_groups
```

And my $this->request->data contain

```
             array(
                 'EmployeeProfile' => array(
                         'first_name' => 'Emppppp',
                          'last_name' => 'kjljj',
                          't_login_id' => '222'
                                        ),
                  'TUserGroup' => array(
                                 (int) 0 => '9',
                                (int) 1 => '13'
                                   ),
              'TAddress' => array(
                               (int) 0 => array(
                                'number_street' => 'emmmm',
                                'area' => '545454',
                                'state' => '2',
                                'city' => '3',
                                                ),
                               (int) 1 => array(
                                   'number_street' => 'empppppp',
                                   'area' => 'nkjk',
                                   'state' => '2',
                                   'city' => '3',
                                  )
                                    )  
                                      )
```

NOW When i try to save using

```
              $this->EmployeeProfile->saveAssociated($this->request->data)

    it will save only EmployeeProfile and TUserGroup Details
```

Ans When i try t save using

```
              $this->EmployeeProfile->saveALl($this->request->data)
         it will save only EmployeeProfile Details..
```

Whats Wrong With me.. i am stucking everywhere...
because every whhere i am using this like relationship . if i can solve this then only i can do the remaining sections. please help me...
i have Posted my whole code here [COMPLETE CODE](http://pastebin.com/s0niDZs6)

Comment: please help me iam stucking a lott

Comment: what is the relation between TEmployeeProfile and EmployeeProfile? Is it $hasOne?

Comment: @FazalRasel if you know the answer pls reply

Comment: there might be minor error...Please, update your question with tables names, model, controller and view... Or you can pastebin all those and provide a link here..

Comment: and most probably its a model naming issue..

Comment: @FazalRasel i have updated my question as you suggested..please give me any solution..iam stucking.

Comment: Well I would like to help you but i need to see all your code and that's why I asked for all your code including `controller`, `view` not just the `model` code. Your question will be very big and messy if you place everything here.. Paste to pastebin.com‎ and give a link on comments.

Comment: @FazalRasel  http://pastebin.com/s0niDZs6 please look at this . i have posted my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question that you need to rethink about the model association. Thus a `TEmployeeProfile` can take many TAddress then you can link model as-

### TEmployeeProfile.php model:

```
<?php
class TEmployeeProfile extends AppModel{
    public $useTable = 't_employee_profile';

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'CommunicationTAddress' => array(
            'className' => 'TAddress',
            'foreignKey' => 'communication_taddress_id'
        ),
        'HomeTAddress' => array(
            'className' => 'TAddress',
            'foreignKey' => 'home_taddress_id'
        )
    );
    public  $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('TUserGroup');
}
```

#### Table schema for TEmployeeProfile:

```
CREATE TABLE t_employee_profile
(
    id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    communication_taddress_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, // this column is mandatory 
    home_taddress_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, // this column is mandatory
    //and your other columns
);
```

### TEmployeeProfilesController.php controller:

```
    public function add(){
        if($this->request->data){
            if($this->TEmployeeProfile->saveAll($this->request->data)){
              $this->Session->setFlash('data saved');
                //redirect to another place
            }else{
                //what you wants to do if save fails
            }

        }
        $TUserGroup = $this->TEmployeeProfile->TUserGroup->find('list');
        $this->set('tUserGroups', $TUserGroup);
    }
}
```

### add.ctp view

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create();

// t_employee_profile
echo $this->Form->input('first_name');

//t_address as CommunicationTAddress
echo $this->Form->input('CommunicationTAddress.street');
echo $this->Form->input('CommunicationTAddress.city');


//t_address as HomeTAddress
echo $this->Form->input('HomeTAddress.street');
echo $this->Form->input('HomeTAddress.city');

//t_user_group
echo $this->Form->input('TUserGroup');

echo $this->Form->end('save');
```

Comment: idea is good, thanks man.
But i told you , the address table is a generic table, it will use everybody . ok anyway i will implement this.